# Zynq/ Petalinux : Unknown command 'gzwrite' - try 'help'

Tags: embedded-linux

For folks familiar with Zynq, Petalinux and u-boot.

I am using a microzed board, and trying to boot it using an SD card. The boot.bin file is generated using Petalinux 2018.3 SDK. The u-boot runs and then gives error `Unknown command 'gzwrite' - try 'help'`.

This error comes while executing the command `install_ext4=gzwrite mmc 0 ${rootfsloadaddr} ${filesize} 0x100000 ${rootfsmmcstart}\0`

I ran `help` command on the u-boot console and `gzwrite` doesn't show up in the list of commands. But the thing is that `boot.bin` was generated by petalinux and that includes the code above to load rootfs.

Do I need to tune up Petalinux project, is my board missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem occurred when,  LC_ALL is set to some languages encoding format such as  "en_US.UTF-8"

That's why before building u-boot, unset the language encoding format as below:-
In the terminal where you are building u-boot  run "unset  LC_ALL".